# Inherit properties from lower media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a wrapper with some divs within. My goal is to display the divs different on different viewports. On smaller viewports than `500px` they should take the whole `width` of `100%` and wrap in a column. On a viewport of `min: 500px` and `max: 768px` they should take `50%` of the row and wrap again (so maximum two divs in a row). On the viewport with `min: 1025px` they should have a with of `1/3` of the whole row and again wrap (so maximum three divs in a row). They also have some spaces on right and bottom solved with `margin`.

**My question:** Is it possible to inherit properties on a larger media query from a lower one? If you take a look on my css, in the first media query `(min: 500px and max: 768)` they get the first time a `margin-right` of `36px`. This `margin-right` should be the same on all wider viewports. My goal was it, just to change the `width` and it would take the `margin-right` which was set last in the css, in this case that one from the lowest media query. At the moment this isn't working. I have to repeat myself and put the same `margin-right` on all medie queries, than it works. Why the inherit doesn't work? He also inherits the display properites for all wrappers without setting it in every media query, why isn't he inheriting also the `margin-right`? Hope it's clear enough.

Here also a codepan, where you can easy resize the screen: https://codepen.io/STWebtastic/pen/zRvdEv

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: strech;
  border: 1px solid lightcoral;
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper__item {
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.wrapper__item:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .wrapper__item {
    width: 47%;
    margin-right: 36px;
    margin-bottom: 36px;
  }
  .wrapper__item:nth-child(2n) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .wrapper__item {
    width: 48%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  .wrapper__item {
    width: calc(100% / 3 - 24px);
  }
  .wrapper__item:nth-child(2n) {
    margin-right: 36px;
  }
  .wrapper__item:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper__item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="wrapper__item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="wrapper__item">Item 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This can’t work as long as you specify a lower _and_ upper boundary for each media query. Whatever you specified for `(min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 768px)` is of course not applicable anywhere outside of those boundaries. The usual way to handle this is that you specify only one boundary - then the properties of the “lower” or “upper” media queries can apply.

Comment: If you want a rule to apply for width larger than X, then just set min-width to X and don't set a max-width

Comment: @Huangism Thanks mate, this solved my problem! Working codepan: https://codepen.io/STWebtastic/pen/zRvdEv

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code just fine tune the numbers to position things correctly:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: strech;
  border: 1px solid lightcoral;
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper__item {
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.wrapper__item:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 500px){ // Changed
  .wrapper__item {
    width: 40%; // Changed
    margin-right: 36px;
    margin-bottom: 36px;
  }
  // Changed
  .wrapper .wrapper__item:nth-child(2) {
    margin-right: 0;
  } // End Change
}

@media (min-width: 769px) { // Changed
  .wrapper__item {
    width: 48%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  .wrapper__item {
    width: calc(100% / 3 - 31px); // Changed
  }
  .wrapper__item:nth-child(2n) {
    margin-right: 36px;
  }

  .wrapper__item:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

Make sure to allocate enough space for each element at each `viewport`

Comment: Please make a working snippet, you can easy answer on my snippet and edit it.

Comment: @MrBuggy all you need to do is set up correct values in pix for the margin and width of the wrapper. It is only 2 min work. It is just easier for you as you know what you are looking at on your end. If you can't figure it out I can give it a go one more time and do it.

Comment: Yes I know, but I'm thinking about the others, who will open this question and see the anwers and can directly compare th snippets and see how it works.